# How to retrieve image from database and display it on view using blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm using

> php artisan storage:link to store the images to database. As expected Images are storing in database. But I've problem in retrieving the images and displaying them on the view.I tried different type of methods but not working. This is my code to get the records.

```html
public function show($id)
  {
    $Attendees=Attendee::where('event_id',$id)->OrderBy('first_name','ASC')->get();
    return view('Attendee',['Attendees'=>$Attendees,'id'=>$id]);
  }
```

This is my code to display data on view.

```html
<div class="col-sm-10" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 225px">
  <a href="{{url('attendeeAdd',[$id])}}"  style="float:right">Add Attendee</a>
  @foreach($Attendees as $deligate)

   <img src="{{ asset('images/$deligate->id') }}"> 
  <h4><span>{{$deligate->first_name}}</span> <span>{{$deligate->last_name}}</span></h4>
  @endforeach

</div>
```

can anyone help me on this please???

Comment: could you post your model, your sql table (at least the image column, is it blob? as far as i know, if you use laravel storage, you are storing in file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that your image is stored into the Database. so you have to retrieve the BLOB data.

```
$blob = $deligate->image_field; // image field name of Table
{{'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $blob ).'"/>' }}
```

Comment: @M.Islamthanks for replying. I've tried it, It is displaying the image path, but not the image.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of time on it, I got the answer.

```html
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images'.$deligate->profile_image) }}">
```

Comment: Hi @Abhilash, this is not storing image in  database, but path to image in database.